# Troubles using a internal hard drive as storage on my Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, storage

Recently I plugged my Ubuntu hard drive into my machine again and since I never ever actually use Ubuntu I just erased Ubuntu so that Windows would detect the drive since it's empty.

Apparently, that's not how this works. So now I have a seemingly empty hard drive and Windows cannot detect it as it doesn't show up in 'My Computer'.

I have also downloaded/installed EasyBCD to see if it had a way of allowing Windows to detect the drive, which came to no avail either.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you need to initialize the disk.  Click Start and Run and type `Disk Management` to bring up the application.  Right click the hard drive you added and select `initialize`.  Then you can format it and Windows will see it.

Comment: Where am I typing "Disk Management"? I pressed Start, then looked for 'Run', found it and typed Disk Management and it said it couldn't be found.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782513(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to Format the drive in Disk Managment

http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=1284

Locate the Drive that had Ubuntu and Format it, be careful when choosing or you could mess up another drive.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/create-format-hard-disk-partition#create-format-hard-disk-partition=windows-7

Once formatted right click on the "empty drive" and select "New Simple Volume"
Choose your letter and call it something like "Data" you should be good to go then!

Comment: Okay I found it and everything is going well.

However, one question; it asks me whether to go with NTFS or exFAT, which is best?

Comment: @Jesse The default in the Windows world is NTFS. But it's up to you to decide.  Go read up on the two formats (start at Wikipedia for instance), and choose which one suits your needs best.

Comment: NTFS... Presumably as FAT32 only allows the transfer of 4GB files each (so I've been reading).